# Match colors in Lightroom to other editing tools

Tags: lightroom, raw, white-balance, color-correction, canon-dpp

I noticed that sometimes Lightroom develops a raw image quite differently from my Canon camera or DPP (Digital Photo Professional by Canon).

Even if in 90% of the cases I'm happy with Lightroom, in some specific light conditions, the difference is very strong, with LR showing skin tones green while DPP has a great light pink tone.

I'm wondering how I could effectively have LR match the way DPP develops the raw.

I tried to change the white balance, exposure and a few settings but it's pretty hard (and slow) to get a similar result.

Comment: Changing the Profile setting in the Camera calibration pane to Camera standard improved the result quite a bit but the two results are still significantly different.

Comment: See also:   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41327/15871

Answer (score 6):

You can't. *Lightroom (LR)* ignores the in camera settings that were in effect at the time the photo was taken and applies its own preset or auto settings.

I'm a Canon shooter. When I first open a Canon raw .cr2 file with Canon's in-house raw convertor, *Digital Photo Professional (DPP)*, the application applies the in-camera settings that were active at the time the image was recorded to the preview I see on my screen. If I export the image as is, the in camera settings are applied to the raw data and the file is exported. Of course I'm also free to change any of the settings I wish before exporting with those settings applied. Most other manufacturer's in house softwares do the same thing.

Most third party RAW conversion software, such as Lightroom or DxO Optics, do not apply the in camera settings. Some of them will allow you to build a custom profile to apply to each image as it is imported or opened. There is still the disadvantage that the same profile will be applied to all images imported as a batch, even if the in-camera settings were different for the different images you shot.

For more on how LR ignores the in-camera settings recorded in the *maker note* section of the EXIF info of a Canon .cr2 file, see [Why do RAW images look worse than JPEGs in editing programs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41327/15871)   and [How to automatically apply a Lightroom Preset based on appropriate (Canon) Picture Style on import](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48431/15871).

---

Note: Since this answer was written we've become aware of a solution provided by Jeffrey Friedl and his awesome Lightroom plugin "[Data Explorer](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer)". It's covered in detail in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/67354/15871) written by [c33s](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26606/c33s).